# try to store base64 pdf file in local storage

Tags: laravel, vue.js

i tried to store my saved base64 pdf files into my public folder in laravel. i wrote this controller to store file.

i tried this controller to decode my pdf files and store it in uploads folder. this request gives base64 pdf file.

```
if($request->get('cv')){

$file = $request->get('cv');                
$ext = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
$newName = rand(100000,1001238912).".".$ext;
$base64 = base64_encode($file);
$file->move('uploads/file', $base64);
$users->cv = $base64; 

}
```

but this method shows me this error.

```
Call to a member function move() on string
```

How can i fix this issue?

Comment: What is your expectations do you want to encode just the name of the file or do you want to encode the contents of pdf file

Comment: @Manojkiran.A i want to decode my encoded pdf and store it in my public folder and then save it with new name into database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

correct answer like this

```
if($request->get('cv')){
   $file = $request->get('cv');
   $base = base64_decode($file);  
   $base64 = time().'.' . explode('/', explode(':', substr($file, 0, strpos($file, ';')))[1])[1];
   $destinationPath = public_path() . "/uploads/file/" . $base64;             
   file_put_contents($destinationPath, $base);
   $users->cv = $base; 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

`$request->get('cv');` will return a string not a file, that is why move() wont work.

Instead of

`$request->get('cv');`

Try to use

`$request->file('cv');`

Comment: @KalanaMihiranga what error you need to provide more information so that we can help

Comment: Thus `dd($request->file('cv');` and post in your question the result

Comment: undefined variable $newName. this is the error shows me

Answer (score -1):

You should use file method for get your input file,

```
if($request->file('cv')){

    $file = $request->file('cv');                
    $ext = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $newName = rand(100000,1001238912).".".$ext;
    $base64 = base64_encode($file);
    $file->move('uploads/file', $base64);
    $users->cv = $base64; 
}
```

Comment: i also tried this but when i try to save this $newName it shows undefined variable $newName error

Comment: Can you give your full controller method where you use your $newName variable ?

Comment: if($request->hasFile('cv')){
                $file = $request->get('cv');
                $destinationPath = 'uploads/file';
                $ext = time().'.' . explode('/', explode(':', substr($file, 0, strpos($file, ';')))[1])[1];
$newName = rand(100000,1001238912).".".$ext;
$file->move($destinationPath, $newName);                
                                        
}  $users->cv = $newName

Comment: this get file cannot use because i get values with vuejs onchange method and this file shows my cv object in base64 type

Comment: this cv file type request result like this . eg: data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xL...........